# Unknown column 'f_data231.f13141' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

```
function process_multiple_selection($post_field_name, $list, $table_field) {
global $query;
global $criteria;
$values = get_post($post_field_name);
if (is_array($values) & count($values) > 0) {
  $query = "$query AND (";
  foreach ($values as $vi) {
    $v = $list[(int) $vi];
    if (isset($v))
      $query = "$query($table_field = '$v') OR";
    }
  $query = substr($query, 0, -3) . ')';
  $criteria++;
  }
}
if ($_POST['sklads_flag']) process_multiple_selection('sklads', $sklads_list, "$orders_table.`f13141`");
```

с чем может быть связана ошибка " Unknown column 'f_data231.f13141' in 'where clause' "

Answer (score 1):

Нет колонки с таким именем, равно как и в коде не видно что за переменная $orders_table и откуда она берется. Проверяй колонку в условии WHERE

Answer (score 0):

В таблице f_data231 нет колонки с именем (алиасом) f13141.

Проверьте правильно ли указана колонка, по которой производить отбор